# display an element when the browser's width is 600px wide or less in css

Tags: css

I want to show my menu when the screen size is less than 600px. As I have added a bar icon when the max-width is less than 600px. I used the following CSS code. But it isn't working as intended.

```
.side-nav{
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .side-nav{
         display:all;
    }
}
```

Comment: `all` is not a valid value for display : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 3):

There is no `display: all`. It should be like this:

```
.side-nav{
   display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
   .side-nav{
       display:block;
   }
}
```

Or one of [these](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) values.